# Why so many calls to the destructor ? Does dereference create a copy on the stack?

Tags: c++, destructor, dereference

Its a complicated piece of code, so apologize for not providing code snippets. In my code I create an object on the heap as follows:

```
{
  State *s = new State();
  ...
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i =0; i < n(blah); ++i) foo(s);
  ...
  delete s;
}
```

`s` is created only once, but passed several times to function `foo(s)`

In function `foo` I have

```
void foo(State *s) {
  State tmp = *s;     // Does this create a copy on the stack ?
  ....
}
```

I can of course avoid creating `tmp` like this, my motivation has been entirely aesthetic (i.e. avoid typing `s->bla()` everytime).

What are the pros and cons of having `State tmp = *s` regarding cache and aliasing ?

What I observe when profiling with `g++-4.6 -pg` is that there are several calls to the destructor of `State` although in the main I create it only once.

So my question is: is dereferencing as `State tmp = *s;` creating a copy on the stack and calling the destructor everytime the scope ends.

My hunch is that assignment operator is getting called to create a copy of the object on stack, which is then getting destroyed. If so, can this be avoided with

```
State &tmp = *s;
```

Comment: Yes, `State tmp = *s;` makes a copy.  Use the reference.

Comment: Thanks all. You just helped remove a performance bottleneck as well. This state object is expensive to copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is exactly as you say. I am not even sure what are you confused about.

Whenever you declare `variable` as `T variable;` there is an instance of `T` created accessible under the name of `variable`.

`T *var` does not create the instance of the `T` but declares "only" a pointer, and `T& var` a reference which essentially is the same, with a little bit different semantics.

In your case, an instance of `T` had to be created. So you would get a destructor call upon the end of scope anyways. I would say from this point of view, the assignment is not that important; just that it makes copy, so you need to make sure the destructor is written correctly. However, whenever you declare a variable of type `T` (i.e. not a reference, or pointer, or anything fancy) a call for the clean up code (destructor) is always generated upon the end of scope when the life of the variable ends.

You can tell everything just by seeing the declaration and understanding what type `tmp` is.

**Also maybe an important note.** To be on the safe side with the correctness, if you switch to a reference, you should probably declare `tmp` as `const State &tmp = *s;`.

Previously anything that was under `...` in foo, would make any changes to the state of `tmp` would make changes only to the copy of `*s`, so `*s` was "safe". Now if anything touches `tmp` you will get visible changes outside of `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

Your hunch is correct, that assignment in function `foo` will each create a copy of that object, which is then destroyed when moving out of the function's scope.
Choosing to have a reference would avoid the copies indeed, which would behave pretty much like using the pointer directly in this case.